# remote form only if user isn't signed in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I just want unsigned-in users to use the form with remote: true but at the same time signed_in users should be redirected normally.
So I tried something like this but it isn't working (doesn't even seem right) but you get the idea:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post, html: {class: "form-horizontal"}) if user_signed_in? do |f| %>
<%= simple_form_for(@post, html: {class: "form-horizontal"}, remote: true) if !user_signed_in? do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your solution does not work because your second call to `simple_form_for` is in the block you just passed to the first call of `simple_form_for`. you could just use the ternary operator to set the `remote` option to true or false, like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post, html: {class: "form-horizontal"}, remote: ( user_signed_in? ? false : true ) ) do |f| %>
```